# problem with char pointer array to parameter of a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, trie

i'm trying to implement TRIE data-structure in C language.
 I have a trie struct,insert function and a main function.

in main function i read a file line by line and splited by space. So i want to take this splited data to insert function by parameter. But when i want to print it, It does not work.

Here is a example

```
struct Trie{
    struct Trie *children[CHAR_SIZE];
    char *value;
};
```

insert function like this

```
void insert(struct Trie **head, char *str, char *value){
.
.
.
.

    curr->value = value;


}
```

and the main function

```
int main() {
.
.
.
           char *name;
           char *value;
           opr = strtok(NULL, " ");
           name = opr;
           opr = strtok(NULL, " ");
           value=opr;

insert(&root, name, value) // this insert code is not working

}
```

if i did like above, it does not work, but if i did like

```
insert(&root, name, "string") // it works
```

it works when i enter the value by manually.

How can i pass value to insert function? Dynamic, static? or else?

thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `struct`, you probably want `char value` and _not_ `char *value`. But, I'm not sure why/how you want your `insert` to have 3 parameters. The usual is: `void insert(struct trie *node,const char *str)` and you traverse and build from there recursively.

Comment: But, you should _edit_ your question and post your _entire_ code in a single code block as what you've posted doesn't show too much.  We should be able to download your code, compile and link it cleanly, and run it with sample data if we so choose. Post some sample data in a separate code block. The sample data should have enough words to cover edge cases (e.g. `cat catty dog doggy dogged can cant cab cabbie cable cap capable capably crab crabby crane the that then togs toggle to todo`).